# Why am I getting a black image after replacing all the pixels of a BufferedImage object with magenta colored ones?

Tags: java, graphics, pixel

I am following a Java Game development tutorial, and I hit a roadblock because I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my code. I am supposed to render a new image by changing each pixel of the buffered image into the color I want. Then I copy that array over to the array in my `Game` class and I draw the rendered image. The relevant code is directly below. I discuss what I have tried directly after the code snippets.

This code snippet is from my `Game` class:

```
private Screen screen;
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

// Converts image into array of integers
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    screen = new Screen(width, height);
    frame = new JFrame();
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}


// Displays images to the screen
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    // Checks if the buffer strategy exists. If it doesn't create a triple buffer strategy
    if(bs == null) {

        // Triple buffering
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    screen.render();

    // Copies array in Screen class to pixels array in (this) class
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

    // Must be in chronological order
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.dispose();

    // Display next available buffer
    bs.show();
}
```

---

This code snippet is from my `Screen` class:

```
private int width;
private int height;
public int[] pixels;

public Screen(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    // Size of the pixels array reserves one element for each pixel
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}

public void render() {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[x + y * width] = 0xff00ff;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to "debug" by checking to see if  both of my `pixels` arrays in the `Game` and the `Screen` class are being loaded with the magenta color. I simply did:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
            System.out.println(pixels[i]);
        }
```

and I also tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
            System.out.println(screen.pixels[i]);
        }
```

In both cases, the decimal representation of magenta (`FF00FF` in Hex) gets printed out until I close the window.

Another thing I tried is using the `image.setRGB`method to change the color of the image.

I added this line

`image.setRGB(20, 20, 16711935);` into the render method as follows:

```
// Displays images to the screen
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    // Checks if the buffer strategy exists. If it doesn't create a triple buffer strategy
    if(bs == null) {

        // Triple buffering
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    screen.render();

    // Copies array in Screen class to pixels array in Game (this) class
    /* for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
       pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }
    */

    // Must be in chronological order
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    image.setRGB(20, 20, 16711935);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.dispose();

    // Display next available buffer
    bs.show();
}
```

A magenta dot showed up in my frame, and I am also able to turn the entire frame into a solid magenta color by modifying the `render` method in the `Screen` class. Now, I am wondering why my "original" code isn't working. From what I understand, the `setRGB` method is much slower than what I originally intended on using to render images, so I don't want to just give up and settle with using `setRGB`.

I have spent practically the entire day going over all the spelling in my code, making sure those nested for loops in the `Screen` class are correct, and etc. I am at a loss here. I don't understand what the issue is.

If the code snippets I included are not enough, I have created a Gist of my code in its entirety [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/51ab674e760b80b37cc3f313a1bc0173).

Comment: Transparency byte ?

Answer (score 0):

This code gets the color int for the input rgb colors

```
public static int getIRGB(int Red, int Green, int Blue){
    Red = (Red << 16) & 0x00FF0000; //Shift red 16-bits and mask out other stuff
    Green = (Green << 8) & 0x0000FF00; //Shift Green 8-bits and mask out other stuff
    Blue = Blue & 0x000000FF; //Mask out anything not blue.

    return 0xFF000000 | Red | Green | Blue; //0xFF000000 for 100% Alpha. Bitwise OR everything together.
}
```

I suspect you are drawing a magenta color with 0% opacity